# $\pi$ as a product of a fraction and $\sqrt2$

Tags: number-theory, pi

I have read that Ramanujan expressed $\pi$ as a product of the square root of 2 and a fraction, but I cannot find the book now. Is this true? If it is, then what is the fraction? Can you please show me a proof if not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by fraction you mean rational number (= quotient of integers), then this is not possible. $q \sqrt 2$ is algebraic for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, but $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: Yes: $\pi = \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: I think you mean the Ramanujan-Sato series, which is an approximation of $\pi$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series)

Comment: @johndoe And, of course, for every finite partial sum, it's a rational multiple of $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $$\begin{align}
> \frac{9801}{4412}\sqrt{2} &= 3.14159273... \\
> \pi &= 3.14159265...
> \end{align}
> $$

This comes from the first term of [Ramanujan series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#20th_century)
$$\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9801}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(4k)!(1103+26390k)}{(k!)^4 396^{4k}}.$$
By taking more terms we can get better approximations. For example, with two terms we get
$$\begin{align}
\frac{2510613731736}{1130173253125}\sqrt{2} &= 3.1415926535897939... \\
\pi &= 3.1415926535897932...
\end{align}
$$
But we will never get exactly $\pi$, since $\pi$ is a [transcendental number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number).

Comment: Note that the numbers in the first two lines aren't equal but just very close to one another. One ends in $73$ but the other one ends in $65$. In fact, there are no integers $a,b$ such that $\frac{a}{b}\sqrt{2}=\pi$ but that doesn't stop us from getting very accurate approximations.

Comment: You could also compute with high accuracy $k=\frac \pi {\sqrt 2}$ and rationalize the result. For $30$ significant figures $k=\frac{3339891201526703}{1503479271462026}$

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.